# ¿Cómo anonimizar columnas y guardar una forma de renombrarlas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Tengo un marco de datos con columnas y filas que me gustaría anonimizar:

```
Comm    asd    toud     tochange
city    12       23       3
cita    43       32       5
...
citu    2        4        5
(vide)                                                          
Total 345      234      121
```

En efecto me gustaria

```
Comm  party1   party2   party3
1     12       23       3
2     43       32       5
...
n     2        4        5
(vide)                                                          
Total 345      234      121
```

Pero también me gustaría mantener una forma de renombrarlas rápidamente.

Hasta hoy hizo:

```
df['Comm'] = 'comm' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['Comm'])[0]+1).astype(str)
```

Pero pierdo el medio de renomrarlos

Comment: Si construyes una clase que emplee la definición estricta de pareja ordenada: `(a, b) = { a, {a, b} }` de modo que `a esté en { city, ... } y b en los ids numéricos` puedes mantener inequívoca la relación y tener un objeto de ida y vuelta.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bastante sencilla es definir un diccionario de doble entrada, algo como esto:

```
cols = {'Comm': 'Comm', 'asd': 'Party1', 'toud': 'Party2', 'tochange': 'Party3'}
cols.update({v:k for k, v in cols.items()})

print(cols)
{'Comm': 'Comm', 
 'asd': 'Party1', 'toud': 'Party2', 'tochange': 'Party3', 
 'Party1': 'asd', 'Party2': 'toud', 'Party3': 'tochange'}
```

Cada clave es el nombre de cada columna, antes y después. Luego simplemente puedes hacer:

```
# anonimizamos las columnas
df = df.rename(columns=cols)
print(df)

   Comm  Party1  Party2  Party3
0  city      12      23       3
1  cita      43      32       5
2  citu       2       4       5

# Reversión de la anonimización
df = df.rename(columns=cols)
print(df)

   Comm  asd  toud  tochange
0  city   12    23         3
1  cita   43    32         5
2  citu    2     4         5
```